# Convert two numeric into a date format

Tags: sas

I have two numeric variables, year and month. year variable has data such as 2010 and month variable has data such as 1 and 10 (1 through 9 doesn't have zero at the front). I need to combine these two variables and then convert it to YYMMn6. format so that I can merge another dataset based on the date.

For example, the input is:

2012 1
2012 10

The output I want is (in YYMMn6. format):
201201
201210

The codes I tried so far:

```
year1=close_year;
year2=clse_month;
yearmonth = cats(of year1-year2); *this results in character variable;
DATE2 = INPUT(PUT(yearmonth,8.),YYMMN6.);
FORMAT DATE2 YYMMN6.;
```

Of course I get an error message. Thanks.

Comment: What error are you getting? Your code works perfectly for me.

Comment: Do you want a character string or a date?  A date is just a numeric.  A format is nothing but direction on how to present that number for human viewing.  Show us what your data look like and we can better help you understand what is going on and how to best accomplish your goal.

Comment: Among other things, why are you doing `put(yearmonth,8.)` and then inputting with `YYMMN6.`?  The main problem you will have is that the month needs to be *two* digits, which it isn't for you.

Answer (score 3):

With numeric variables I'd use MDY function rather than putting and whatnot; you're having trouble here because `20101` isn't a valid YYMM value.

```
dateval = mdy(monthval,1,yearval);
format dateval yymmn6.;
```

Note that the 'final' date format is wholly unrelated to whatever you use to input the date variable from an informat; there's no difference from SAS's point of view between

```
dateval = input('01JAN2010',DATE9.);
format dateval YYMMN6.;
```

and

```
dateval = input('201001',YYMMN6.);
format dateval YYMMN6.;
```

The input/informat is converting a value into a numeric number of days since 1/1/1960.  The final format is telling SAS how to display that newly created number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the answer mentioned by Joe which

- would give you the flexibility to change to a different format if you want later on,
  without any hassle.
- would keep the variables in numeric format,    so mathematical or
  date functions would be easy to apply.

or you can use

```
mydate=put(mdy(monthval,1,yearval),yymmn6.);
```

if you want the output in char format.

Both are correct. Choose as per your requiremnt.

Comment: That's a very different thing from what my answer gives, actually; that puts a character value in `mydate`, while my answer puts a numeric value with a format in `mydate`.  One or the other may be optimal depending on ultimate use.

Comment: Totally agreed with you Joe. Though Jimmy has an option now. 
Most of the times I personally use the answer mentioned by you, because 
(i)It gives me the flexibility to change to a different format, without any hassle.
(ii)It keeps the variables in numeric format, so mathematical or date functions are easy to apply.

Although my answer would work fine as well for Jimmy, but it would be particularly appropriate when the output is required in char format.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you should mention this difference in the answer, as the way you put it in the answer makes it sound like it's identical, which it is not.